# Error: [$compile:tplrt] Template for directive must have exactly one root element

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I know this question has been asked a bunch of times before, I read through the answers, tried the offered solutions, but I'm still getting the error and I'm not sure why. I stripped my application down to a simple hello world to try and figure out why its happening.

```
            <!--index.html -->
                <!DOCTYPE html>
            <html lang="en" ng-app="app">
            <head> 
                    <script
                    src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"
                    integrity="sha256-FgpCb/KJQlLNfOu91ta32o/NMZxltwRo8QtmkMRdAu8="
                    crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
            <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.5/angular.js"></script>
            <script type="text/javascript" 
            src="./controller/MainController.ctrl.js"></script>

            </head>
            <body >
                <div ng-controller="HelloController">
                    <test-dir/>
                </div>
            </body>
            </html>

             //controller/MainController.ctrl.js
             var app = angular.module('app',[]);
             app.controller("HelloController", function($scope) {
             });

              app.directive('testDir', function (){
             return {
                restrict:'E',
                replace:true,
                template:`template/helloWorld.template.html`
             };
          });

   <!--template/helloWorld.template.html -->
   <div>
       <h1>hello, is it me you're looking for</h1>
   </div>
```

Comment: use templateUrl instead of template option.

Answer (score 0):

if you are providing the link to the template file you should use `templateUrl` not `template`.

If you want to use `template` you have to write

```
"template":"<div>...</div>"
```

Answer (score 0):

Change from template to templateUrl

```
`template:`template/helloWorld.template.html`
```

to

`templateUrl :`template/helloWorld.template.html

Comment: when i use templateUrl i get this error twice Error: [$compile:tpload] Failed to load template: template/helloWorld.template.html (HTTP status: -1 )
as well as Cross origin requests are only supported for protocol schemes: http, data, chrome, chrome-extension, https.